# *ngFor is updating before it gets the new data

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, asynchronous

I am currently working on a "Meeting List" where the user can create new Meetings and join other meetings.

My Stack looks like this:

- FrontEnd: Angular
- API: Firebase Cloud Functions
- DB: Firebase realtime DB

  ---

  For the list of meetings, I am using this markup as it should render a list of every Meeting with its name.

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Aktuelle Meetings</h2>
  <div class="cardContainer" *ngFor="let meeting of meetings">
    <div class="meeting">
      <div class="meetingText">
        <p class="titleText">{{ meeting[1].title }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="createMeeting">
    <button class="floating" mat-fab (click)="openCreateMeeting()">
      <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

`openCreateMeeting()` is opening a MaterialDialog (Angular Material) where the user can put in some basic information about the meeting.

```
  openCreateMeeting(): void {
    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
    dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(NewMeetingComponent, dialogConfig);

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((data) => {
      this.getMeetings();
    });
  }
```

`getMeeting()` sends an API call to get the meetings from the DB.

---

When the user creates a new event it triggers my ´apiService´ which includes the functionality to create a new meeting.

```
 public postMeeting(
    eventTitle,
    eventDescription,
    eventLocation,
    eventDate,
    eventOwner
  ): void {
    console.log('creating an event ...');
    const data = {
      title: eventTitle,
      description: eventDescription,
      location: eventLocation,
      date: eventDate,
      owner: eventOwner,
      participants: eventOwner,
    };
    this.httpClient.post(this.apiUrl, data).subscribe((data) => {
      console.log('Event created');
    });
  }
```

However, when I am creating a new event the new Event doesn't show up on the list. It refreshes before the new item gets back from the API/DB. So the new event only shows up when I either refresh the page or create the next item.

[image: GIF of the problem]

What I want to do now is to somehow wait for the API call to finish before refreshing my `*ngFor`.

**Question:** So how would I go about waiting for the data to appear before re-rendering the *ngFor?

---

What I tried:

I tried to include the `changeDetector.markForCheck()`.

```
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((data) => {
    this.getMeetings();
    this.changeDetector.markForCheck();
});
```

Included the changeDetector directly into my `getMeetings()`.

```
public getMeetings() {
    const meetings = this.httpClient.get(this.apiUrl);
    this.changeDetector.markForCheck();
    return meetings;
}
```

This didn't solve the problem, but crashed my application and gave me this error:

```
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[MeetingListComponent -> ChangeDetectorRef]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for ChangeDetectorRef!
NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[MeetingListComponent -> ChangeDetectorRef]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[MeetingListComponent -> ChangeDetectorRef]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for ChangeDetectorRef!
    at NullInjector.get (core.js:778)
    at resolveToken (core.js:2564)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:2490)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:2353)
    at resolveToken (core.js:2564)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:2490)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:2353)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:26403)
    at NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:27491)
    at injectInjectorOnly (core.js:657)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:797)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:754)
    at zone-evergreen.js:858
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:34182)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:390)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:168)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone-evergreen.js:559)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone-evergreen.js:469)
    at invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:1603)
```

This didn't do anything since angular is probably getting the check but the new data isn't there yet.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm are you sure your API finishes the POST request before you call the GET request? I would advise 1 of 2 things:

- Call your `this.getMeetings();` right after your POST method response and not when you close the dialog.
- If you are adding a new meeting why not simply add that meeting to the meetings list? you can either do it after the POST response with data from your server or directly with the values inserted in the form

Comment: On your 2nd idea. So currently I am getting the whole list of meetings. Instead, I should try to just get the latest meeting and then append it to my current list? Did it my way because I thought it might be easier (seems I'm wrong)

Comment: @Ironlors What I meant in the 2nd idea was that ideally in Restfull API's you want to return a 201 created at on Http Post methods that add records which returns your added meeting , no need for a get last meeting.

Comment: and then I can just take this data from the response and add it to my list? Well, I am returning the meeting but haven't thought about using it this way :O.
Currently, it just exists for the purpose of debugging.

Comment: Yes you avoid 1 list request which is a better approach especially if you are intending to target mobile users to avoid big data transfers often.

Answer (score 0):

show this meeting in the list directly when you tap submit and give it a `saving` status, then wait for db saving.

Answer (score 0):

I would add the close modal function inside of the post request callback, that way the modal does not close before the meeting is saved in db. something like this.

```
this.httpClient.post(this.apiUrl, data).subscribe((data) => {
  console.log('Event created');
  this.dialogRef.close()
});
```

A better option is to look at rxjs Subject.

Comment: the post request is handled by the service. But I could try some kind of callback function. This could then close the modal as soon as the POST is completed.

Comment: do not subscribe from the service. just return this.httpClient.post(this.apiUrl, data). then subscribe from your modal component.

Answer (score 0):

add `private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef` in your constructor, then in your getMeetings function add `this.cdr.markForCheck();` after this.meetings is populated.

example:

```
getMeetings() {
        ....
        ....
        // response API service
        this.meetings = response;
        this.cdr.markForCheck();
    }
```

Comment: I tried this one before (forgot to include it in the post, but did so now). It didn't solve the problem (reasons in the post)

Comment: you must add `this.cdr.markForCheck();` inside getMeetings() functions, after meetings is populated.

Comment: same problem as before. But this time it came with a huge error message (because it seems like it doesn't want to add the change detector to the constructor).